# Is this Question really locked?

Tags: support

I tried to vote on this question *[Why are there such outdated and terrible answers to questions here?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17833/why-are-there-such-outdated-and-terrible-answers-to-questions-here)) but got a red alert:

[image]

There is no indication in the question that it is locked - how come?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the question in question? It might have gotten locked or deleted after you loaded the page.

Comment: @ByteCommander done, thx for the reminder

Comment: I've unlocked the question. That probably shouldn't happen for posts migrated to meta.

Comment: @ThomasWard I know the technical reasons why the post got locked. I meant that I disagreed that the lock should happen at all for meta posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed this bit under the question itself:
[image]

**Votes, comments and answers are locked** due to the question being closed here, but it **may be** eligible for editing and reopening on the site where it originated.

So *it may be*, but *it wasn't*...

#### ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

<sub>Emphasis mine, but *maybe* the mods can change that and add the same emphasis so this doesn't happen any more in the future...</sub>

Comment: Ah, I **really** should read the whole label :-), I stopped reading at "...rejected". It never ocurred to me, that this could imply a lock.

Comment: @guntbert: I had the same happening to me a few hours ago, but reading everything before asking a meta question solved my problem.  **:D ;-) :D**

Comment: Well ...: asking before reading everything obviously worked too :-)

Answer (score 3):

Just to shed some more light on what happened under the hoods, causing this whole confusion, I reconstructed the history of this post (including only the here relevant events). All times are UTC on the day when the question was posted.

- **12:38** — question **asked** on the main site.
- **13:16** — **migrated to Ask Ubuntu Meta** due to five close/migration votes.
  This automatically **closes and locks the main site post** and sets up a redirection to its equivalent on Meta.
- **13:21** — question **closed as unclear on Meta** by moderator.
  Closing a migrated question automatically **rejects the migration**, **locking the migrated version** and **unlocking the original post** on the main site again.
- **13:44** — the original **question on the main site gets deleted** by moderator.
  In the timeline it says "via Vote" and the post got "red-deleted" (deleted with at least one helpful red (spam or rude/abusive) flag, hiding its content (btw. yes, nested braces are weird, and yes, the term "red-deleted" was just made up by me)), so I assume it got deleted from the moderator flag queue.
- **22:07** — the Meta post gets [manually unlocked by a moderator](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17834/is-this-question-really-locked#comment37381_17834).

Sources: [original question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024654/why-are-there-such-outdated-and-terrible-answers-to-questions-here) / [migrated Meta question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17833/why-are-there-such-outdated-and-terrible-answers-to-questions-here) / [original timeline](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1024654/timeline) / [Meta timeline](https://meta.askubuntu.com/posts/17833/timeline)
<sup>Note: Some of these links might only be visible to users with enough reputation.</sup>

So now we have the original question on the main site being deleted and its migrated, closed (therefore rejected and locked) and then again finally reopened counterpart on Meta.

Comment: Exception: closing a migrated question on the target site *as a duplicate* (which does not apply here) does not cause the migration to be rejected [(I think)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)